# How to check at runtime if a particular method is run by a test case or not

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven and TestNG.
How to distinguish at runtime when a particular method is being called by a TestNG/JUnit test-case or by the main java code

Comment: you want a code coverage tool like jacoco or cobertura

Comment: Clear case of an XY problem. If you need to know this sort of thing there is something wrong with the problem you're trying to solve. The method should behave identicallly, whoever called it.

Comment: Guys, you're being WAY TOO HARSH. This is a great teachable moment for Pitt, and we should give him a better way to accomplish what he's trying to do, instead of criticising what is obviously (to us) a bad approach.

Answer (score 3):

Several comments are alluding to this, however it's generally extremely poor practice to build in statements that work one way under test, and another way when the app is running standalone.  This increases the probability that the app will pass tests, but fail in production.

Instead, you should look at why you're wanting to make this distinction.  In general, it will be for the sake of some dependent object, or due to input of one variety or another.  In these cases, it's better to engineer the class to accept dependent objects to be inserted into it via configuration and under test, the only thing that changes is the configuration. The class under test should not distinguish the dependant classes from one another. Instead, just work with their interfaces, so you can create mock classes for testing.

When accepting input, redirect the input source to take scripted input.

For databases, redirect to an in-memory DB which is configured for the test, etc.

You will find this approach will VASTLY improve the quality of the code you write, and decrease the probability of bugs sneaking past your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, your code is **never** running unit tests. Unless you invoke them explicitly from your code, which you should never do.

Unit tests are only run manually, or during the test phase of the maven lifecycle.